# Is it safe to use flax thread for cooking?

Tags: equipment, slow-cooking, utensils

I was not able to get hold of hemp thread and so I bought flax (100%) thread instead. It smells a bit funny, but is it safe to use for cooking? I plan to use it for a bouquet.

Comment: Not sure what country you're in. If it smells I wouldn't use it for cooking, but you might be able to soak in hot water to remove the smell/taste. I'd go for cotton thread. Hemp comes from the same plant as marijuana so growing is highly regulated in the US.